# 16.04 constantly reconnecting to WiFi

Tags: networking

Using Ubuntu 16.04, my computer is constantly reconnecting to my WiFi network. This wasn't an issue in previous releases.

Here's some info about my system:

```
**System:**    Host: kerubin-F80L Kernel: 4.4.0-21-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 5.3.1)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.28) Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial

**Machine:**   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: F80L v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: F80L v: 1.0 Bios: American Megatrends v: 206 date: 08/06/2008

**CPU:**       Dual core Intel Pentium Dual T3200 (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3) bmips: 7980
           clock speeds: max: 2000 MHz 1: 2000 MHz 2: 1667 MHz

**Graphics:**  Card: Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) 

**Resolution:** 1280x800@59.91hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version: 2.1

**Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering:** Yes

**Audio:**     Card Intel 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-21-generic

**Network:**   
Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: b800 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: ens32 state: down mac: 00:22:15:ff:7c:23

**Card-2:** Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
           driver: ath5k bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wls33 state: up mac: 00:22:43:17:9e:4b

**Drives:**    HDD Total Size: 160.0GB (6.1% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST9160827AS size: 160.0GB

**Partition:** ID-1: / size: 14G used: 5.2G (40%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: /home size: 45G used: 2.2G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 2.03GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda8

**RAID:**      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present

**Sensors:**   System Temperatures: cpu: 76.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
**Info:**      Processes: 202 Uptime: 32 min Memory: 649.4/2005.8MB Init: systemd 
**runlevel:** 5 Gcc sys: 5.3.1
           Client: Shell (xfce4-terminal) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: Right Click on the wireless icon in panel, select "edit connections", select wireless, select the name of your Access Point, click edit, untick "Connect Automatically", and Save.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. WiFi connection is lost after a few minutes

Comment: @7_R3X, Ubuntu 16.04 currently has a wifi bug that has been causing major issues for many users. There's also other bugs.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

Answer (score 1):

Set the  [WIFI country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) for the Kernels current regulatory domain if it isn't set

```
iw reg get
```

To set it

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
REGDOMAIN=<ISOCODE>
```

Reboot.

Comment: the problem is not only WiFi, but also in a wired network